# Ошибка в коде с циклом и break

Tags: python-3.x, while, break

Всем привет, в моем коде возникла ошибка, которую даже представить не знаю как решить. Ошибка заключается в том, что выбирается рандомное число от 0 до 1, если число равняется 1, то по идее выполняется break и соответственно должно выходить из цикла. Но почему-то это не происходит и код идет дальше (если бы число равнялось 0). Вроде раньше все было хорошо, но вчера возникла эта ошибка, пытался поискать ошибки, но нигде ничего не нашел. Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо!

```
def MeetMonster():
    Shrek.Level = rd.randint(1, 3) * Pl.Level
    Shrek.Hp = rd.randint(3, 10 * (Pl.Level)) * Shrek.Level + Pl.Damage
    Shrek.Damage = (Shrek.Level * 4) * Pl.Level
    Monster = rd.choice(Shrek.Name)

    print("Ты набрел на монстра - {0}, у него {1} уровень, {2} здоровья и {3} урона".format(Monster, Shrek.Level, Shrek.Hp, Shrek.Damage))
    sleep(0.4)
    print()

    while True:
        choice = input("Попытаться убежать или будешь сражаться (бег/атака)?: ").lower()
        print()
        sleep(0.4)
        if choice == "бег":
                                      *Ошибка здесь*
            if rd.randint(0, 1) == 1:
                print("Фух, пронесло...")
                print()
                break
            else:
                print("Монстр оказался чересчур сильным и догнал тебя...")
                print()
                sleep(0.4)
                break
        elif choice == "атака":
            break
        else:
            continue
                          *Из-за этой ошибки оно запускает вот это:*

    while Shrek.Hp > 0:
        if Pl.Critical >= rd.randint(1, 10):
            Shrek.Hp -= Pl.Damage * 2
            print("Вы нанесли критический удар!")
            sleep(0.4)
        else:
            Shrek.Hp -= Pl.Damage
        sleep(0.4)
        print("Ты атаковал монстра и у него осталось", Shrek.Hp, "здоровья")                         
        sleep(0.4)
        print()

        if Shrek.Hp > 0:
            if Pl.Dodge >= rd.randint(1, 10):
                Pl.Hp -= 0
                print("Вы уклонились!")
                sleep(0.4)
            else:
                Pl.Hp -= (Shrek.Damage - Pl.Armor)
                if Shrek.Damage < 0:
                    Pl.Hp - 0
                print("Монстр ударил тебя и у тебя осталось", Pl.Hp, "здоровья")
            print()
            sleep(0.4)
        else:
            corruption = Pl.Corruption
            corruption = 2
            xp = Pl.Xp
            xp = rd.randint(25, 50) * Shrek.Level
            loot = rd.randint(5, 25) * Shrek.Level
            if Pl.PlusMonsterCoinDrop > 0:
                Pl.Coins += (loot * Pl.Level * (1.0 + Pl.PlusMonsterCoinDrop))
                Pl.Xp += (xp * (1.0 + Pl.PlusMonsterCoinDrop))
                Pl.Corruption += 2
                Pl.Score += 120
            else:
                Pl.Coins += (loot * Pl.Level)
                Pl.Xp += xp
                Pl.Corruption += 2
                Pl.Score += 100
            print("Тебе удалось одолеть монстра, за что ты получил", loot, "монет,", xp, "опыта", "и", corruption, "единиц искажения" )
            print()
            LevelUp()
            sleep(0.2)
            PrintCorruption()
            PrintCoins()
            PrintXp()
            PrintHp()
            print()
            Pl.MonsterKilled += 1
        if Pl.Hp <= 0:
            break
                      
                                *Функция "произведения" ситуаций*
def GameLoop():
    Place = rd.randint(1, 1000)
    if Place == Place > 50 and Place == Place <= 250:
        Pl.Score += 25
        MeetMonster()
        sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Какое желаемое поведение вы имеете ввиду? Выполнение не должно переходить в цикл `while Shrek.Hp > 0`?

Comment: Да, так так раньше и было. Но вчера что-то случилось, что break не выполняет свою функцию, либо я накосячил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно, чтоб функция прекращала работать, то вы можете воспользоваться `return`:

```
if rd.randint(0, 1) == 1:
    print("Фух, пронесло...")
    print()
    return
```

То есть, после выполнения данного условия, действия не перейдут в `while Shrek.Hp > 0:`

Comment: @LirkNess если ответ вас устроил, пожалуйста, оцените голосом)

Answer (score 0):

```
break
```

Прерывает только текущий цикл

```
 while Shrek.Hp > 0:
```

у тебя будет запускаться всегда когда HP > 0.
Советую вынести это в отдельную функцию.

```
while True:
    choice = input("Попытаться убежать или будешь сражаться (бег/атака)?: ").lower()
    if choice == "бег":
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
            print("Фух, пронесло...")
            print()
            break
        else:
            print("Монстр оказался чересчур сильным и догнал тебя...")
            break
    elif choice == "атака":
       battle():
       break



def battle():
   # Твой код
    pass
```

А вообще так как у тебя цикл находится в функции можно сделать `return` в место `break`если тебе не нужно дальнейшее выполнение кода.

так же тебе не нужна конструкция

```
else:
    continue
```

Так как твой цикл ничего не прерывает, он будет крутиться и без этой конструкции

```
continue
```

Используется для досрочного перезапуска цикла

Comment: Спасибо большое! К сожалению нельзя поставить два ответа правильных(. Но я пока-что откажусь от дополнительной функции, мороки много)